# xdaliclock in gnome-screensaver

Tags: gnome, screensaver

At the moment I use xscreensaver with [xdaliclock](http://www.jwz.org/xdaliclock/). Now I want to replace xscreensaver with gnome-screensaver. Now my question is: How to configure gnome-screensaver to use xdaliclock?

Comment: A more general question would be how do you configure gnome-screensaver.

GNOME's screensaver utility does not display or give options to display advanced screensaver options. For an explination on why from the GNOME developers please read the following:

http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why_doesn.27t_the_screensaver_preferences_tool_allow_me_to_change_the_settings_for_the_theme.3F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you enjoy ;-)

**If you're lazy and just want it to work, run this at terminal and choose XDaliClock:**

```
cd ~/ && wget dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/xdaliclock.sh && chmod +x ~/xdaliclock.sh && ~/xdaliclock.sh && rm ~/xdaliclock.sh
```

**Step by step instructions:**

1) Install some apps:

```
sudo aptitude install gnome-screensaver xdaliclock xscreensaver-data
```

2) Create a file:

```
gedit ~/xdaliclock
```

3) Then paste this into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=xdaliclock
GenericName=XDaliClock
TryExec=xdaliclock
StartupNotify=false
Exec=xdaliclock -root -font BUILTIN3 -24 -cycle -visual best
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Screensaver;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
```

4) Save the file

5) Move the file:

```
sudo mv ~/xdaliclock /usr/share/applications/screensavers/xdaliclock.desktop
```

6) Create a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xdaliclock /usr/lib/xscreensaver/xdaliclock
```

7) Open the Screen Save Preferences

```
gnome-screensaver-preferences
```

8) Choose xdaliclock

9) Enjoy!

[image]

[image]

Reference: http://my.opera.com/pau4o/blog/2009/07/07/xdaliclock-started-via-gnome-screensaver

Comment: It worked for me. What do you mean by seems to have no effect? Can't you see the xdaliclock option? May be I can help further. Look: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/xdaliclock.1.jpg and http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/xdaliclock.2.png

Comment: @desgua, yes in the screensaver-preferences dialogue is no entry called xdaliclock.

Comment: Would you please download this file http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/XDalibydesgua.sh and this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/XDaliClock.desktop into your home folder (~/) and the run this command: "sudo chmod +x ~/XDalibydesgua.sh && ~/XDalibydesgua.sh" without cotes on the terminal?

Comment: @desgua: Thanks. I tried it, however there is no xdaliclock entry in the screensaver-preferences dialogue

Comment: The terminal showed some error? What is the content of your folder /usr/lib/xscreensaver/? The file /usr/bin/xdaliclock exist?

Comment: http://justpaste.it/a04, http://justpaste.it/a05

Comment: Then, would you please post here step by step what did you do (because probably you made some mistake).

Comment: I've made some changes and I've made a script too. Would you please try it?

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I think the point is, that one has to reinstall gnome-screensaver to apply changes done manually in /usr/share/applications/screensavers/ !? Is it possible to change the background color to black and the font color to white? I added-bg black and -fg white to the Exec line, however there is no effect.

Comment: Ok, I have to remove -cycle

Comment: Glad it work. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A more general question would be how do you configure gnome-screensaver.

GNOME's screensaver utility does not display or give options to display advanced screensaver options. For an explination on why from the GNOME developers please read the following:

http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why_doesn.27t_the_screensaver_preferences_tool_allow_me_to_change_the_settings_for_the_theme.3F

This is probablt not the complete answer but here's my best shot:

- Press alt-f2
- Insert the text "gconf-editor" in the box and click "Run" button
- Press ctrl-f
- In the search type in "screensaver"
- At the bottom, notice "/apps/gnome-screensaver" - double click this

Now this is the point where I'm not too sure. In this path key you will find a key "themes". Try to fill this field with either:

[xdaliclock]

OR

[screensaver-xdaliclock-slideshow]

It is possible that these two screensavers are not compatible unless programmed into gnome-screensaver, but you would have to ask gnome developers.

Comment: Thanks, however it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Convert xdaliclock.xml to a .desktop file

```
How come my xscreensaver "hacks" don't show up in the gnome-screensaver
configuration tool?  

gnome-screensaver uses standard desktop entry (.desktop) files to
define the screensaver themes. Xscreensaver XML configuration files
can be converted into .desktop files using the
migrate-xscreensaver-config.sh script in the data directory of
the gnome-screensaver sources.
```

from [here](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Can_I_use_xscreensaver_.22hacks.22_with_gnome-screensaver.3F)

this is essentially what desegua said with less detail but a reference
it also uses the configuration tool instead of copy and paste from a code box
to try and eliminate a possible source of error.

if his solution didn't work try this instead of the .desktop paste

Comment: There is no xdaliclock xml file. I just have the following line in my .xscreensaver file:-    xdaliclock -root -noseconds -24 -builtin2   \n\